# listView Sort, First column,Int Descending.... C#?

Tags: c#, listview, sorting

I am trying to "sort" a column of a ListView in c#.

I would like to sort just the first colum, If i set the "sorting" properties to "descending", it sorts my data like this:

and it sorts my data-set like this:

> 96
>
> 876
>
> 76442
>
> 6
>
> 56
>
> 100000

(notice its not really descending, exept for the first char...)

How would i correct this so the ENTIRE number is considered when sorting?, so 1000 is more then  500, currently it just reads the first char and makes 500 bigger then 1000.

I did some searching, seems i may need a "customer" sorter, Can anyone assist me?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx  
MAy be my answer?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Looks like a reverse string sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a string-sorting issue. You might want to check that the data you are sorting is numeric data and not string data (note that many list view implementations will call ToString() on an object to get its value, causing the value to be string).

Comment: hey Omer thanks mate, yes its a string, when i need it to be a int :(..
Thanks for lending a hand.

Also

 
codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx

is worth a look for anyone with the same issues.